# DGET fails to lookup properly when two entries are similar

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I am running into a weird DGET error in Google Sheets.

in one table, I have the following entries:

```
Column A        Column B
Horse           Wins
Daedalus I      15
Daedalus II     12
Panacea I       10
Panacea II      9
```

when I use

```
=dget(A1:B5,"Wins",{"Horse";"Daedalus I"})
```

I get a `#NUM!` error. However, if I change the table from "Daedalus II" to "Daedalus 2", the error is gone.

- Is this the expected behavior or a bug in Google Sheets?
- Any way to circumvent this without changing the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@James/mreighties posted an answer on Google, that I am copying here for future reference:

Hello,

I may have found the answer at this site...

https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/exact-match-in-database-functions-in-google-sheets/

...and changed your formula to this...

```
=dget(A1:B5,"Wins",{"Horse";"=Daedalus I"})
```

...and it works for me. Take a look at my testing sheet...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EoTytnKAIrrRmRwPX9k2xdEKeJMk4i5O3BtIXjaVSc4/edit?usp=sharing

...where in `F2` is this formula...

```
=dget(A1:B5,"Wins",{"Horse";"=Daedalus I"})
```

...which hardcodes the criteria in the formula.

And in `H2` is this formula...

```
=dget(A1:B5,"Wins",{"Horse";"="&D2})
```

...which looks at the choice made from the drop-down in `D2` to use as the criteria in the formula.

James :)

Comment: Something I didn't know. Still. This will work in your case where the values present are NOT repeated. Will fail though if they are because  *"`DGET` is the only database function that does not aggregate"*

Answer (score 0):

From the Google official support site

> `DGET` is the only database function that does not aggregate – it will return an error if the filtered data has either no matching elements or more than one matching element.

So yes. This is the expected behaviour.

As your best alternative would be to use the `QUERY` function

```
=QUERY(M1:N,"select N where M='Daedalus I' ",1)
```

**OR**

```
=QUERY(M11:N16,"select N where M matches 'Lucky M' ",1)
```

[image]

Of course you will argue
*"But `Daedalus I` is not the same as `Daedalus II`"*
Correct.

**What happens with `DGET`?**
You should think of `DGET` as an alternative of the `where` QUERY clause.
The sting comparison operators would be `matches`, `contains`, `like`, `starts with`, `ends with`.

**`DGET` is an alternative for the `starts with` in a `QUERY`**
**But `DGET` does NOT aggregate**.
Thus the error.

---

**EDIT** *(after taking a look at your sheet)*

You can also use

```
=QUERY(A1:B,"select B where A matches '"&D2&"' ",0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! See also a way to force DGET to get exact matches in my own answer, above

Comment: **Thank you**. Something I didn't know.